curl update in Alma9
our vulnerability management team classifies this CVE in curl as crtitical:
https://curl.se/docs/CVE-2023-38545.html
We are using Alma 9.4 and the newest curl Version provided bei Alma is 7.76.
But the smallest Version of curl to mitigate the problem is 8.4.0
What is the best way to update curl on Alma 9?
Actually we built curl 8.8.0 from sources, but not with all features as in the official distro, since then many, many other dependent packages would have been built first.
https://git.almalinux.org/rpms/curl/src/tag/imports/c9/curl-7.76.1-29.el9_4/SPECS/curl.spec
I am mainly wondering why I have not found anybody else on the internet asking for the same.
Bonus Question: Why Alma9.4 (or RHEL9.4), which was just released, provides a 3-years old version of curl!?
Many thanks
Michael

Does this answer your question? How do I check to see if Redhat (CentOS) has backported a security fix for Samba?

You cannot solely check version numbers. Distros such as AlmaLinux strive to maintain stable versions through their support period, and backport fixes to older versions. You have to check if that's the case here. The reason they provide a three year old version of curl is because ... that's the point. It should behave in the same way as the day it was released, without new features, but also without new bugs or interface changes! If you read the RPM spec you linked to (search for 38545 in it), you will in fact see that they've back ported it.

If you are using a custom build of this, please link to your source so we could reproduce the build. Unlikely to find many people willing to assist you in something custom, but that is better than getting a definitely wrong answer from people assuming you are using the distro's builds.

Thanks for the hint @vidarlo.
That explains all the patches in the spec-File, which i just quickly removed without reading :(.
And there you find it immediatly.
# return error if hostname too long for remote resolve
Patch33:  0033-curl-7.76.1-CVE-2023-38545.patch

so, no need to update anything.
